# using mkl, error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so

Tags: matrix, fortran, intel-mkl

I'm almost new in using `mkl` libraries. So excuse me if it seems silly.  I tried to run an example in tutorial [[here]](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/529744) with `ifort -mkl dgemm_example.f` ,then run the executable file. Here is the error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also searched for the similar problems but it baffled me more.
do you have any idea? 
[dgemm_example.f](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsx9i8taxynodby/dgemm_example.f?dl=0)

Comment: How do you initialize the intel compiler? Did you source the compilervars.sh ?

Comment: yes I did : It give me : ERROR: Unknown switch ''. Accepted values: ia32, intel64

Comment: now I get this error after source that: `./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: You must do `source the_file intel64` if you have a 64 bit system (otherwise ia32).

Comment: Excuse me how to do that ?

Comment: `source compilervars.sh intel64`

Comment: after source like that I have still that `libiomp5.so` error

Comment: Use ifort -openmp and no just ifort -mkl.

Comment: If that edit is in fact an answer it should be entered as an answer and not as en edit to the question. I am still puzzled why it didn't work using `compilervars.sh`.

Comment: perhaps `source compilervars.sh` is not enough to say `loader` to find shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, otherwise the shared library will not be found at run time.

Before running your program, type `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/library/directory` in the (bash) shell in which you want to run your code.

If you are using Ubuntu, you can set this variable automatically by using configuration files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`, see [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables). Similar mechanisms are available for other distributions.

Comment: That is normally done automatically by the configuration script I referenced.

Comment: I have already copied this in my .bashrc file: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/mkl/lib/intel64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
`. It's linux Mint

Comment: Yes, sorry Vladimir, I hadn't read your comment when I typed the answer.

Comment: No problem, just saying that the problem is more to get the correct directories, than the fact they need to be in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1):

I'm using CentOS on our workstations. Adding following lines to *bashrc* worked for me.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/intel/bin"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PATH:opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the address of libiomp5 in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/icc.conf` and used `sudo ldconfig`.

There is another way that every time we should use this flag: `-Wl,-rpath=/opt/intel/directory/to/library/directory`

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CentOS and intel compiler.
Type 
`locate  compilervars.sh`


Go to your '.bashrc' file and add

```
source /adress you got from locate command/compilervars.sh intel64
```

Then in terminal type
`source ~/.bashrc`

It will fix the error.

Comment: And if there's no `locate` installed, or more than one `compilervars.sh` is available, or the user isn't in a bash shell?

Comment: You can install `locate` from repository I guess. I don't know how to deal with multiple `compilervars.sh` problem. Maybe he/she can try using all the addresses available or choose intuitively. I am new to all these stuff, but I am trying to suggest what I did to fix this error. Hope it helps.

Comment: How do you go to your .bashrc file? where is it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried

```
pip install mkl
```

and export the path.

I works.