# Compile R with Intel MKL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu, intel-mkl

I installed Intel MKL library by running this:

```
# keys taken from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-free-libs-and-python-apt-repo
wget https://apt.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB
apt-key add GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS-2019.PUB

sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://apt.repos.intel.com/mkl all main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-mkl.list'
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install intel-mkl-64bit
```

I added this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

If I try to compile R with Intel MKL it doesn't work:

```
cd R-3.4.2
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
MKL="-Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_gf_lp64 -Wl,--start-group -lmkl_gnu_thread  -lmkl_core  -Wl,--end-group -fopenmp  -ldl -lpthread -lm"
./configure --prefix=/opt/R/R-3.4.2-intel-mkl --enable-R-shlib --with-blas="$MKL" --with-lapack
make && sudo make install
```

Error message:

```
/home/pacha/R-3.4.2/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_gf_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But it works compiling with OpenBLAS:

```
cd R-3.4.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/R/R-3.4.2-openblas --enable-R-shlib --with-blas --with-lapack
make && sudo make install
```

It works with Ubuntu 17.04+ but not with 16.04 just like this other question [using mkl, error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046753/using-mkl-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libmkl-intel-lp64-so)